# Отключить открытие sys.stdin и sys.stdout вместо файлов

Tags: python, argparse, stdin

Можно ли отключить поведение "открывать <stdin>, если передана пустая строка или дефис" без написания собственного хендлера?

```
parser.add_argument('file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
```

Comment: Передавайте параметр как строку, а открывайте файл сами.